# Magento 2 CE for official site vs Magento 2 CE from github

Tags: magento2, theme

Is there a difference between Magento 2 CE from official site and Magento 2 CE from github

Because I could not find many folders and files, and the file and folder structure is different.
What is better for beginners?
I want to customize the blank theme, but when I follow the tutorial many folders and files are missing form Magento 2.0 from the official site

Comment: in that case you can search vendor/magento folder.

Comment: is app/code/Magento/Catalog/ as same as vendor/magento/module-catalog. because I could not find Catalog folder under vendor/magento

Comment: yes, app/code/Magento/Catalog/ as same as vendor/magento/module-catalog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are referring to are different versions for different needs:

**GitHub links**

- https://github.com/magento/magento2

This is the version to use when you want to contribute to the Magento 2 codebase as a developer.

- https://github.com/magento/magento2-community-edition

This is the version to use when you want to set up a new shop based on Magento 2

**Download versions**

The download version is actually the same as the `magento2-community-edition` from GitHub. Use this if you don't want or can run the composer setup.

This link from the Magento 2 docs describes which version is the best for which need:
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/continue.html

Comment: Thank you Anna Völkl for the informations really it is very helpful

Comment: +1, good explanation, short and sweet. You also have the option to download an [archive like `.zip`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/zip_install.html) and extract it in your web server's docroot. For all intents and purposes, this is the same as [`composer create-project`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install.html).