# Which branch should be cloned for a production site?

Tags: magento2, installation, git

From the [install guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/dev_install.html):

> You can clone either a release branch or the develop branch: Release branches like 2.0 or .2.0.1 are more stable
>   develop is more recent.
>   Currently, the develop branch is the default but you can clone a release branch like **2.0.1** using the optional -b  argument.

However, the [branches list](https://github.com/magento/magento2/branches/all) on github shows only:

-Develop (green mark)

-merchant_beta (red mark)

-2.0 (red mark)

Which branch should I clone to get the latest version for a production site?

Comment: You're mixing up different versions for different needs... see also here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97633/231

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is official document on how to install Magento: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install-quick-ref.html

We recommend to clone repository only if you are planning to contribute back to Magento 2 source code.

Comment: Magento documentation like a roller coaster .... more you read, more you want to read again.... then you have just time wasted, left no money and a headache...

Comment: Would you mind giving an example? We're always looking for ways to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Only composer shold used for production site. git is only for development

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Composer?

`composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition`

Comment: No error. Just make sure that you have swap configured on your server.